# Mesh default when I try to texture it

Tags: texturing

First I'm sorry, because I'm going to talk about other software...however, I know that the original problem should comes from the way I've used Blender in order to make this mesh (but I don't know why..), so here is my problem :

I've made an asset and I'm trying to texture it in substance, however things not working as usual and there is what happen for this time :
[image]

[image]

[image: Zoom on the High Poly Mesh]

There is like black shadows lines and I really don't understand why.. this "artefacts"? happens in high poly & in Low poly.

Do you know why guys ? And how to fix this ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are these '' lines '' seen only in rendering view? Upload a screenshot in edit-mode view or else try to upload the file, maybe looking at it closely we can solve your problem. However, if you haven't done it, I suggest you proceed with the usual basic precautions: check if the object has double faces, double edges or vertices. Are there any lights? let us know.

Comment: Hello @Albizz thanks a lot for your answer. I'm sorry if my explanation wasn't clear enough, but this "lines" are not visible in Blender (however not as far as i know). But visible in other softwares, like Unreal Engine 4 & also in Substance Painter. So I think that the problem come from the model itself and how i've made it. Regarding faces/edges/vertices i've not found anything wrong. If needed, i can send FBX. Again : Thanks a lot

Comment: So the screens you put on, are they about substance and unreal? I am not an expert in the sector, I hope you can answer whoever is competent, but I am not sure that the error could be due to blender. Let's say it is possible that you did not export the file correctly or that something is missing from reading by other software. However, I advise you to upload the file again, so those who read and understand export can take a look.

Comment: Exactly, the 2 first screenshots comme from Substance painter. I've tried to export it again, I will try different way to do it..for now, still searching ! Thanks again for your help & support @Albizz